# Magento: local admin redirects to live site after correct login

Tags: magento

I installed my Magento shop locally (xampp) and modified the base urls in `core_config_data`. The shop frontend works fine. When I access my admin area, it is still on localhost (http://localhost/my-shop/admin), so that works as well.

As soon as I try to login to the admin area though, it redirects me to my live shop, but only if the login data is correct. If I enter wrong data, it displays the "Wrong login" message. I cleared the cache but this does not help.

What else could be the reason?

Thanks!

Comment: clear `log_url` table , `cache` and `session`

Comment: Nice ideas, but they do not help. I cleared /var/cache, /var/session and the log_url table ... did not change a thing. Btw: I updated my question, it only happens for correct login data.

Comment: is your live admin working on https?

Comment: Yes, it is ... could that be the problem? My local base urls are http though.

Comment: check for base_secure_url too in core_config table.

Comment: is it solved the issue?

Comment: Which one do you mean? I changed web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url to my local URL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93656/discussion-between-arnie-and-urfusion).